# Why does the output value of my AOP change?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I want to retrieve voltage and make some operation with it, so I used an AOP to follow the voltage.

[image]

Whithout R6 and R5 in open circuit, the AOP follows the signal, however  when I put voltage divider bridge after Vs, Vs changes, so the AOP doesn't follow the signal as the prior circuit whithout R6//R5. Is this normal?

How can I retrieve voltage only depending on inputs to do some operation after Vs?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTMBrZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. Original schematic redrawn by @Transistor.*

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show your full schematic with the voltage divider and all component values, power supply voltages and op-amp part number and link to datasheet if it's needed. We can't guess.

Comment: Since R2>>R1, It is like a voltage follower. Meantime, you can get rid of R2 at all. The problem sounds like the loading. What is you "voltage divider" total resistance? Is the OPA powered and grounded correct? What is the part number of OPA?

Comment: Yes this is a total resistance. The only problem is that the source ground of my circuit is the same ground of the OPA powered

Comment: (1) What is AOP? Do you mean an op-amp? (2) Are you really using a TL081? If not then please correct your schematic. Use the op-amp symbol with the power pins and show what voltages you have connected them too. (3) Check the datasheet. Will your op-amp drive a 200 ohm load? (It seems very low.) (4) How close to the supply voltage rails will your op-amp go? Many will only get to about 2 V above negative supply and 2 V below positive supply. (5) Why are you attenuating (dividing) **before** the op-amp and again **after** the op-amp?

Comment: No this is a TL082IP, I edited the circuit

Comment: No, you didn't fix the schematic. We still don't know what op amp you are actually using or what supply voltage you actually have. We can't give you good advice if you hide all of the important information.

Comment: I've redrawn your schematic to make it clearer. It's still showing your op-amp powered from a 1 V supply. That's not going to work. Notice that you haven't clarified four of the five points I raised in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage divider you added to the output is a load of only \$200\,\Omega\$. Assuming that you operate the op amp with reasonable supply voltages this load is probably drawing more current than the op amp can supply, so the output voltage falls.

Comment: You're right, can you explain me that, I don't understand why

Comment: A real op amp can not supply an unlimited amount of current, and you are asking for too much. A typical specification is that the load resistance must be \$10\,\text{k}\Omega\$ or higher.

Answer (score 0):

To make a voltage follower with an op-amp, do not use a resistor in the feedback path. Your circuit should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NUXz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

In your newly added schematic, you have +1V connected to the op-amp positive power supply pin, and 0V connected to the op-amp negative power supply pin. This is a mistake. The op-amp will not run with only 1V supply. Does the schematic reflect your actual circuit, or is that an error in your schematic only?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this, but even with this configuration, Vs change if I add voltage divider after.

Comment: What is the purpose of your voltage divider? Of course a voltage divider will give a lower output voltage than input voltage. That is its purpose. Also, what op-amp are you using? Part number?

Comment: Ok, I have in V+  a voltage that I want study in raspberry, however my raspberry doesn't take 20V , I can't put voltage divider directly because it will affect my circuite before, I search a way to analyse my Voltage independently of my circuit ( without affecting my circuit).

Comment: Is it more clear the the edited circuit ?

Comment: Thank-you for the schematic. Now where in your schematic is the voltage different from what you expect? Where is the Raspberry Pi in your circuit?

Comment: As you can see on the circuit, this is on Vs. Thank you very much

Comment: @kodi You can try to use more resistance in the voltage divider so that less current flows.

Comment: Thank you, it works, Elliot Alderson has already answered.